How to efficiently process millions of local files using .NET Framework and async I/O?
I need to process one big repository (the source repo) and create/update (or leaves intact) about 2M files in another repo (the metadata repo).
Although there are ~2M of files, most of them are only read to verify their contents does not need to change. In any single run of the processor maybe a few hundreds of files are actually written.
My current implementation does NOT use async I/O, even though I would love to. There is a complication, which prevents me from finding a good solution.
Indeed, my code is the consumer part of a producer/consumer pipeline, where some code produces the content of metadata files (by processing the source files, but the producer piece is not the subject of this question), puts it onto a blocking collection (I call it the bus) and my code consumes from the bus concurrently from multiple threads.
But more importantly, it contains 2 distinct phases:

Phase 1 - While a background task that collects the names of all the existing metadata files is running. While in this phase:

The code uses File.Exists to check if a metadata file exists (all are local files).
The names of the visited metadata files are recorded in a dedicated collection named processedFiles.


Phase 2 - After the aforementioned background task has completed and the names of all the existing metadata files are collected into the existingFiles collection. While in this phase:

The code checks if a metadata file exists by looking up in the existingFiles collection.
The names of the visited metadata files are removed from the existingFiles collection.



The challenge is implementing the transition between the two phases without loosing any "packets" on the bus.
I was able to code it relatively easily with Parallel.ForEach, but now I want to use async I/O and wonder what are my options.
I have a big constraint - I must use the .NET Framework. I deplore it, but it is what it is.
I would like to show the essentials of my code, mainly to show how I implement the transition between the phases.
private class EndWorkItemsParallelState
{
    public readonly StringBuilder StringBuilder = new(1000);
    public readonly Guid Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
}

private Task GetEndWorkItemsConsumer(BlockingCollection<EndWorkItem> endWorkItems, int concurrency) => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> existingFiles = null;
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> processedFiles = new(C.IgnoreCase);

    ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ManualResetEventSlim> locks = [];
    object modeSwitchGuard = new();

    Func<string, byte[], bool> saveJsonFileIfDirty = (filePath, newContent) => SaveIfDirty1(filePath, newContent, processedFiles);

    Parallel.ForEach(endWorkItems.GetConsumingEnumerable(), new ParallelOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = concurrency
    }, () =>
    {
        EndWorkItemsParallelState state = new();
        if (existingFiles == null)
        {
            locks[state.Guid] = new ManualResetEventSlim();
        }
        return state;
    }, (endWorkItem, loop, state) =>
    {
        ProcessEndWorkItem(endWorkItem, saveJsonFileIfDirty);

        if (existingFiles == null && m_collectExistingFilesTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            locks[state.Guid].Set();
            lock (modeSwitchGuard)
            {
                if (existingFiles == null)
                {
                    foreach (var @lock in locks.Values)
                    {
                        @lock.Wait();
                    }

                    existingFiles = m_collectExistingFilesTask.Result;
                    foreach (var processedFile in processedFiles.Keys)
                    {
                        existingFiles.TryRemove(processedFile, out _);
                    }
                    processedFiles = null;
                    
                    saveJsonFileIfDirty = (filePath, newContent) => SaveIfDirty2(filePath, newContent, existingFiles);
                }
            }
        }

        return state;
    }, state =>
    {
        if (locks.TryGetValue(state.Guid, out var @lock))
        {
            @lock.Set();
        }
    });

    locks.Values.ForEach(o => o.Dispose());

    DeleteStaleFiles(existingFiles.Keys);

    void ProcessEndWorkItem(EndWorkItem endWorkItem, Func<string, byte[], bool> saveJsonFileIfDirty){ ... }
    static bool SaveIfDirty1(string filePath, byte[] newContent, ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> processedFiles){ ... }
    static bool SaveIfDirty2(string filePath, byte[] newContent, ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> existingFiles){ ... }
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

The transition is implemented here:
if (existingFiles == null && m_collectExistingFilesTask.IsCompleted)
{
    locks[state.Guid].Set();
    lock (modeSwitchGuard)
    {
        if (existingFiles == null)
        {
            foreach (var @lock in locks.Values)
            {
                @lock.Wait();
            }

            existingFiles = m_collectExistingFilesTask.Result;
            foreach (var processedFile in processedFiles.Keys)
            {
                existingFiles.TryRemove(processedFile, out _);
            }
            processedFiles = null;

            saveJsonFileIfDirty = (filePath, newContent) => SaveIfDirty2(filePath, newContent, existingFiles);
        }
    }
}

When a thread detects that the phase 1 should be over it tries to enter the critical section (only one succeeds) and then waits for ALL the other threads to hit the critical section and block on it. It knows when other threads reach it, because each thread has its own ManualResetEventSlim instance which they signal when they get to the critical section. The thread that is inside it, waits for all these signals. Once all are set, it means all the threads are blocked at the critical section and it is safe to perform the transition between the phases.
Since posting this question I have found a solution, but I wonder if it can be improved.
EDIT 1
Each work item on the bus contains the file path and the new content. The processing checks if the file exists AND the new content is really different (by reading the existing file and diffing). If the content is different OR the file is new - the new content is written out AND another file is created in another repo.
At the end I need to delete all the stale files, i.e. those which were never visited. That is why I collect all the existing files.

There is a Parallel.ForEachAsync implementation for .NET Framework here. Also check the package System.Threading.Channels. It supports .NET Framework 4.6.2.

@TheodorZoulias - the provided polyfill using TPL does not allow for thread local state, which my current implementation depends on.

Thread-local state and asynchronicity are incompatible. You either have to get rid of the thread-locals, or stick with the synchronous implementation.

It is not a real thread local. I just used the term to describe the state managed by Parallel.ForEach.

Ah, you mean the Parallel.ForEach overload with localInit/localFinally parameters. There is no such overload for the .NET 6 Parallel.ForEachAsync either. If you want to switch to async, you have to get rid of it. The closest analog is the AsyncLocal<T> type, which I wouldn't advise anyone to use. It creates more problems than it solves.

Are the processed files on the local disk?

Yes, they are. So File.Exists is fast.

Tbh: I think your description and the code aren't quite the same. And the description doesn't make much sense to me. In order to use File.Exists there must be knowledge of a path beforehand, right? So, where does Phase 1 take that from? And in the description, Phase 2 seems to be just confirming the findings of Phase 1. The code, however, seems to do some updates on files' content ... which makes this a little more complex. Now we have to deal with file system locks etc ...

"Yes, they are." - then arguably I would not switch to async processing here - in my personal experience (though I have not tested it again for a long time), there were not much benefits from using async IO in such cases.

I checked it. If I keep concurrency = 1, the overall code takes about 30% longer to run.

@Fildor - Let me post a clarification.

"the new content is written out AND another file is created in another repo." - Just a wild thought ... do you really need those files in the filesystem? Or would it be an idea to consider using a database? Which could not only hold the content and a "virtual path" but also a content fingerprint (for fast change-detection) - at least for everything not in "the other repo" ... again: just letting my mind run wild ...

I actually need both :-). There is another process that syncs the first repo into a Redis database. It runs disconnected from this one.

Here is my solution:
ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> existingFiles = null;
ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> processedFiles = new(C.IgnoreCase);

Func<string, byte[], CancellationToken, Task<bool>> saveJsonFileIfDirtyAsync = (filePath, newContent, ct) => SaveIfDirty1Async(filePath, newContent, processedFiles, ct);

var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, concurrency).Select(async _ =>
{
    try
    {
        while (!m_collectExistingFilesTask.IsCompleted && await endWorkItems.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token))
        {
            while (!m_collectExistingFilesTask.IsCompleted && endWorkItems.Reader.TryRead(out var endWorkItem))
            {
                await ProcessEndWorkItemAsync(endWorkItem);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) when (e is not OperationCanceledException)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        throw;
    }
}));

existingFiles = m_collectExistingFilesTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
foreach (var processedFile in processedFiles.Keys)
{
    existingFiles.TryRemove(processedFile, out _);
}
processedFiles = null;

saveJsonFileIfDirtyAsync = (filePath, newContent, ct) => SaveIfDirty2Async(filePath, newContent, existingFiles, ct);

await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, concurrency).Select(async _ =>
{
    try
    {
        do
        {
            while (endWorkItems.Reader.TryRead(out var endWorkItem))
            {
                await ProcessEndWorkItemAsync(endWorkItem);
            }
        }
        while (await endWorkItems.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token));
    }
    catch (Exception e) when (e is not OperationCanceledException)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        throw;
    }
}));

progressHelper.Done();

async Task ProcessEndWorkItemAsync(EndWorkItem endWorkItem){ ... }
static Task<bool> SaveIfDirty1Async(string filePath, byte[] newContent, ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> processedFiles, CancellationToken ct){ ... }
static Task<bool> SaveIfDirty2Async(string filePath, byte[] newContent, ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> existingFiles, CancellationToken ct){ ... }

EDIT 1
Based on the valuable input from @TheodorZoulias I have introduced cancellation token to facilitate failing fast. The local method ProcessEndWorkItemAsync captures the cancellationTokenSource object and the saveJsonFileIfDirtyAsync delegate. It passes
cancellationTokenSource.Token to the captured saveJsonFileIfDirtyAsync delegate.
When any task fails, it cancels the token and it would cancel all the other concurrently running tasks.

The await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, concurrency) is a worse version of Parallel.ForEachAsync. In case a ProcessEndWorkItemAsync operation fails one worker Task will be killed, but the remaining tasks will keep going. The concurrency will be reduced. If you are unlucky to have exactly concurrency - 1 early exceptions, the last standing worker will slowly process the remaining elements alone, until the exceptions are finally surfaced. The correct behavior is to terminate the whole operation ASAP when an exception occurs.

Also the while (!m_collectExistingFilesTask.IsCompleted && await endWorkItems.Reader.WaitToReadAsync()) nested loop is a slightly worse version of the existing ReadAllAsync API. It is worse because the IsCompleted check is redundant. You can find the correct implementation in the source code. You could make an extension method to accommodate for the lack of this API on .NET Framework, if the IAsyncEnumerable<T> type is available.

@TheodorZoulias - would you mind posting your own answer? Sounds like it is better and I would like to credit it.

I've already linked a Parallel.ForEachAsync implementation for .NET Framework, with almost identical behavior with the real thing. It's here.

@TheodorZoulias - that is not the same. I looked at that link. If that link was really an answer, then my question would have been a duplicate, but it is obviously not. Your answer could be very beneficial and not just to me.

@TheodorZoulias - I have implemented your first comment about failing fast. But I do not understand what am I supposed to do with the m_collectExistingFilesTask.IsCompleted check. I do not see it as redundant, could you elaborate?

Did you just take the answer you had earlier from chat gpt and pot that here?

Not really. I did originally paste the answer from Chat GPT with some minor adjustments. But that one is not it. If you want to compare, here is the link to the Chat GPT chat - https://chatgpt.com/share/66e90794-aea4-8004-82d4-7804f7454019. The final answer from Chat GPT was similar to my original code with a single loop and synchronization in order to transition between the two phases. My current answer is different, but I did use elements suggested by Chat GPT, like using the Channel API. But no, the final answer is not that of Chat GPT.

Mark your question is not very enticing to me for 2 reasons. 1. .NET Framework 2. Focuses more on an obscure implementation, and less on the overall scenario, desirable behavior etc.

I am not happy about the ,NET Framework either, but my hands are tied. As for the second item - you can clarify all that in an answer. This way it may be helpful to many people. But ultimately, up to you.

Questions are not clarified by answers. They are clarified by editing and improving them. To be honest I think that at this point this question is beyond repair. If you are interested to ideas and solutions, you could consider posting a new question where the focus would be on the scenario and its requirements, providing all the essential details about the desirable behavior of the overall operation.

For what it's worth, I modified the question.
